# Tumblr.js 401 Unauthorized

Tags: node.js, api, reactjs, npm, tumblr

what's wrong with this?

```
var tumblr = require('tumblr.js');
var client = tumblr.createClient({
  consumer_key: '...',
  consumer_secret: '...',
  token: '...',
  token_secret: '...'
});

client.userInfo(function (err, data) {
    if (err)
        console.log(err);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data,null,'\t'));
});
```

Every key is in its place and anyways in Chrome Console "401 unauthorized"!
I'm making it on localhost with 'simple-react-app' and official 'tumblr.js' module. What it can be? By the way methods for blogs works fine but for user - info, dash, all failed.
[image]

Comment: you can't use it in the browser, add it in your server code...

Comment: can you point me to an example, please?

Comment: try to use express for your server, can't find an example  ^^

Comment: where are you using the client ?

Comment: I'm using  client in a React component

Comment: Err, if the url string is constructed correctly you can use it to test in the browser. http://imgur.com/a/mgdtF it should return json data (as long as it is authorized etc)

Comment: Man, method blog works fine. Anyways, I've already understand that I can't do this task without backend on Express.js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### 401 Unauthorized

> If the request already included Authorization credentials, then the 401 response indicates that authorization has been refused for those credentials.

See: [W3/protocols](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.2)

### In the Browser

> Due to CORS restrictions, you're going to have a really hard time using this library in the browser. Although GET endpoints on the Tumblr API support JSONP, this library is not intended for in-browser use. Sorry!

https://github.com/tumblr/tumblr.js/#in-the-browser

### Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)

> The Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) mechanism gives web servers cross-domain access controls, which enable secure cross-domain data transfers. Modern browsers use CORS in an API container - such as XMLHttpRequest or Fetch - to mitigate risks of cross-origin HTTP requests.

See: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)

### Tumblr console

Try your code here, and review your api keys and tokens (if they are wrong they can cause the 401 error )

https://api.tumblr.com/console/calls/user/dashboard

### Tumblr Api

You can use the normal api ( that's just a wrapper for node.js ) :

Just do a `GET` request:

```
api.tumblr.com/v2/user/info
```

See: [API](https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2)

## SuperAgent

> SuperAgent is a small progressive client-side HTTP request library, and Node.js module with the same API, sporting many high-level HTTP client features.

```
request
  .get('http://api.example.com')
  .auth('user', 'pass123')
  .end(callback);
```

See: [Docs](http://visionmedia.github.io/superagent/#authentication)

## Example

> **Note:** this is just a quick and dirty implementation of `tumblr.js` and `react`, please don't use this code directly and instead make your own implementation.

BTW: PRs are welcome!

#### [github/btzr-io/react-tumblr](https://github.com/btzr-io/react-tumblr)

**Setup:** Install dependencies and run `npm start` to start the server

```
 npm install & npm start
```

Remplace `MasterKey` with your actual tokens / keys in `dist/server.js`:

```
// Authenticate via OAuth
const tumblr = require('tumblr.js');
const client = tumblr.createClient(MasterKey);
```

Comment: So, how can I use this API in React, can you point me to an example, please, or tutorial? I really can't understand.

Comment: @EzhiMakov what are you trying to do? ^^

Comment: I'm trying to get my dashboard/feed posts and show'em in my way on page

Comment: did you try to use the api (http request) instead of the client ??  ^^

Comment: @EzhiMakov Added an example ^^